# How to get the last, by the code, printed text Python

Tags: string, python-3.x

Let's say my code looks like:

```
print('Hello World')
```

result:

```
>>>Hello World
```

How can I retrieve what has been printed and put it in a string or in a list of strings if it's more than one print (for example by saying from where to where it should get them)

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on what exactly you're trying to do? There may or may not be easy solutions depending.

Comment: @glibdud so I have a large Code, with many .py files and at certain point of the code I would like to get what has been printed in the console and use it for example in an: if  string == 'string': do... and the string to compare with is the last printed text by the code. (for example: can I read what is in the console, or start recording at a certain point and stop at another an as a result I get a list of strings with all the prints that has been run)

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the print function, and do something along these lines:

```
import sys

last_out = ''


def print(message):
    global last_out
    last_out = message
    sys.stdout.write(message+'\n')

print('derp')
print(last_out)
```

Output:

```
derp
derp
```

You could also save the message in an array, and retrieve the last x amount of strings for example

Comment: This will get all the prints, which is not really useful when I have a very large Code with many prints. This will slow down the code.

Comment: Is there not a method of the stdout that does record what has been written in the console?

Comment: whats the functional difference? if all prints are recorded, then its the same as literally reading the console, since all prints are already there right? If you know the specific bits of code that you may wish to record, use a custom print function for those, instead of replacing all prints @AnasBouayed

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you could occasional clear the array, just like how the console will start deleting lines above a certain line count. But this is the same as stdout recording the output

Comment: Yes, that could be possible, but when you have a very large code, you're not sure from which code part this result will be comming there are many possibilities, so this will be a big change in the code. the answer is working, but I'm looking for something more efficient that at a certain point of the code gets the last printed line

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that recording the whole console lines is not that good as an Idea, best would be to get the last line or a certain number of lines would be optimal